# Joining 3 Tables Together - One of the tables returns null results. How can I ignore this table in my WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, left-join

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing. Basically, I have three tables:

- MainTable
- ItemsTable
- ObjectsTable

Where the ID (PK) on MainTable are foreign keys on ItemsTable and ObjectsTable (So MainTable will never return null in my query).

Now the goal is to join them all on ID and then execute a WHERE clause **using all three tables**. Here is the query:

```
select * from MainTable as a
left outer join ItemsTable as b
on a.ID = b.ID
left outer join ObjectsTable as c
on a.ID = c.ID
where 
a.ID = 9999 AND
(a.StatusOne = 1 and b.StatusOne = 1 and c.StatusOne = 1) AND
(a.StatusTwo != 1 or b.StatusTwo != 1 or c.StatusTwo != 1)
```

The idea of the query is that if it returns any results, a variable in my code is set to true and false if vice versa.

**This works perfectly only if every table has an ID.** However, I ran in to a case where ItemsTable doesn't have any records with that ID, and thus the query returned no results, when it should have.

My question is:

**How can I ignore a NULL joined table in my WHERE clause? So if ItemsTable is NULL, I still want to execute the condition, just *without* `b.StatusOne` and `b.StatusTwo`**

Comment: Moving the qualifying statement to the Where clause makes your left outer join INNER Joins.   Move the "(a.StatusTwo != 1 or b.StatusTwo != 1 or c.StatusTwo != 1)" up to the join statement

Comment: provide raw data sample and expected result please, sqlfiddle would be very helpful. _variable in my code is set to true and false if vice versa._ I see no variables in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the qualifying statement to the Where clause makes your left outer join INNER Joins.  Below will work.

```
select * from MainTable as a
  left outer join ItemsTable as b
       on a.ID = b.ID and b.StatusOne = 1 and b.StatusTwo != 1 
  left outer join ObjectsTable as c
       on a.ID = c.ID c.StatusOne = 1 and c.StatusTwo != 1
  where 
    a.ID = 9999 AND
   (a.StatusOne = 1 and 
   (a.StatusTwo != 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move those related conditions to the `JOIN ON` clause instead in `WHERE`

```
left outer join ItemsTable as b
on a.ID = b.ID and ( b.StatusOne = 1 or b.StatusTwo != 1)
left outer join ObjectsTable as c 
on a.ID = c.ID and (and c.StatusOne = 1 or c.StatusTwo != 1)
where a.ID = 9999 AND (a.StatusOne = 1  or a.StatusTwo != 1);
```